# Generate one time URL

Tags: urls

I need to implement one time URLs in a wordpress website.
I found this script on [phpclasses website](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9634-PHP-Generate-URL-that-only-works-one-time-for-the-user.html) and I integrated it in wordpress and it seems to work.

I think this script can also be useful to other users, and so I'd like to ask if someone can help me.

In my case, the script is rewriting the URL, but when I click on it, it redirects me to a 404 page. Is it possible that the problem is in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the problem is in the .htaccess file?

Almost certainly. Double check that you've updated the correct .htaccess file - and that your host supports using .htaccess files! See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, my host supports using .htaccess files. 

If I write RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^faked/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]  "faked" is removed from url but still refer to page 404. 

Is anybody interested in this script?