# Implement One Time URL Script

Tags: php

I need some help, I need to implement a one time url for my wordpress website I found an answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224897/generate-one-time-url)
I need help implementing the script in wordpress. the script link is [here](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9634-PHP-Generate-URL-that-only-works-one-time-for-the-user.html). any help would be appreciated Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I copied the script and added it to my wordpress files, then i called the script in the theme function.php, when that didnt work i added the the php script using the php script insert plugin. still didnt work

Comment: basically what i am trying to achieve is in this corona pandemic, my company has started working with restaurants for taking orders from the parking area. A QR code is placed in the parking zone, when scanned open ups the menu url, now the issue is we want each scan be with a unique url, (one time url) so that some one dont order it from anywhere else. we are using wordpress at the moment, any idea how to implement the one time url? Hope i can get some help in this. thank you